# Xamarin.iOS prevent Xcode Autogenerate viewcontroller.cs

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working with a Xamarin.iOS project with Visual studio 2019 for mac, but I make the StoryBoards and modify them from Xcode because Vs always causes me problems. Now the problem I have since the last xcode update (Version 11.6 (11E708)) is that after opening a Storyboard with xcode, it automatically generates the controllers of these storyboards duplicating it in the project. My question is, is there an option in xcode that I can disable so that it stops generating the viewcontrollers automatically?

Thank you

Comment: So it's a problem of XCode?

Comment: I think so it's xcode

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of VS Mac. Try download the last major VS Mac release (8.6) [Here](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/68ffa29a-6a5b-41f7-af7b-506ddcf4bbfc/6f601f3b5ff4d19ecd2c258517acc562/visualstudioformac-8.6.2.6.dmg)

Follow the open issue [Here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/9372)